# How to pass data from child module to parent module?

Tags: terraform

I know the steps to pass data from parent to child module. But how to pass the data from child module to the parent module. for ex: child module creates ec2 instance and public IP data needs to be passed from child module to parent module

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible as long as the child module declares output values:

> The resources defined in a module are encapsulated, so the calling module cannot access their attributes directly. However, the child module can declare output values to selectively export certain values to be accessed by the calling module.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/syntax#accessing-module-output-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use outputs for this.  In the following child module that performs a simple EC2 creation:

main.tf:

```
data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

You can create an output of the public IP so that other resources/modules at the parent level can reference it.

outputs.tf

```
output "public_ip" {
  description = "The public IP of the web EC2 instance"
  value = aws_instance.web.public_ip
}
```

More information on [outputs here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/outputs).

Comment: Where's the child module in your example?

Comment: The main.tf and output.tf would be in the child module folder that the parent module is sourcing.